# Access EJB from Application Client (project configuration)

Tags: java, client, ejb, enterprise

I know this has been asked before, but i can't find a good answer

So I want to have an client application that calls remote ejbs.

For this i have 2 ear applications.
One ear with the ejb module, and another ear with the application client module.
In the client module i am trying to inject in the Main() class the EJB with @EJB annotation.

**application.xml for the EJB:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com    /xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns    /javaee/application_5.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="5">
  <display-name> 
      MppL4_SERVER</display-name>
      <module>
         <ejb>MppL4_SERVEREJB.jar</ejb>
      </module>
 </application>
```

**application.xml for the app-client:**

```
<application 
  <display-name> 
      MppL4_CLIENT
  </display-name>
  <module>
     <java>MppL4_CLIENTClient.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
     <ejb>MppL4_SERVEREJB.jar</ejb>
  </module>
</application>
```

If i deploy both ears on the Glassfish server i get:

```
EVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:216)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while binding JNDI name entities.PersonAPIRemote__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__ for EJB : PersonAPI
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1530)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.initializeHome(StatelessSessionContainer.java:197)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:207)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.AlreadyBound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/AlreadyBound:1.0]
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.ExceptionMapper.mapException(ExceptionMapper.java:75)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.callBindOrRebind(CNCtx.java:595)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.bind(CNCtx.java:620)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.bind(CNCtx.java:658)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:400)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishCosNamingObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer$JndiInfo.publish(BaseContainer.java:5482)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1515)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.AlreadyBound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/AlreadyBound:1.0
    at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.AlreadyBoundHelper.read(AlreadyBoundHelper.java:60)
    at org.omg.CosNaming._NamingContextStub.bind(_NamingContextStub.java:67)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.callBindOrRebind(CNCtx.java:584)
    ... 41 more

SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:216)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while binding JNDI name entities.PersonAPIRemote__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__ for EJB : PersonAPI
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1530)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.initializeHome(StatelessSessionContainer.java:197)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:207)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.AlreadyBound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/AlreadyBound:1.0]
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.ExceptionMapper.mapException(ExceptionMapper.java:75)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.callBindOrRebind(CNCtx.java:595)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.bind(CNCtx.java:620)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.bind(CNCtx.java:658)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:400)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishCosNamingObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer$JndiInfo.publish(BaseContainer.java:5482)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1515)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.AlreadyBound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/AlreadyBound:1.0
    at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.AlreadyBoundHelper.read(AlreadyBoundHelper.java:60)
    at org.omg.CosNaming._NamingContextStub.bind(_NamingContextStub.java:67)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.callBindOrRebind(CNCtx.java:584)
    ... 41 more

WARNING: Exception while cleaning module 'org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef@1e493eb'java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.AppClientDeployer.clean(AppClientDeployer.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineInfo.clean(EngineInfo.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.clean(EngineRef.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle$1.actOn(ApplicationLifecycle.java:224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:342)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

My app-client main class:

```
public class Main {

    @EJB
    private static PersonAPIRemote personApi;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("client started...");

        //Person p = new Person(3, "lololol", 456);
        personApi.service();

        System.out.println("client ended...");
    }

    /* (non-Java-doc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#Object()
     */
    public Main() {
        super();
    }
```

I am using GlassFish Tools Bundle For Eclipse as an IDE.

Comment: I redone it but i have another problem now. I now have a single java enterprise application with both the ejb module and the application client. when i deploy the main() method is not being executed. i put a break-point in it, and system.out.printlns and wont get to them. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what i done is:

1. Use JNDI

   ```
   Context ctx = new InitialContext();
   personService = (PersonApiRemote) ctx.lookup("api.PersonApiRemote");
   ```
2. Add all Glassfish jars (which are a lot!) to the Application Client's build path.

Comment: I want to ask a question , if I have nothing to do with EJB , just a main application does it make sense to run it as application client. For example a job which will pull some record from DB every 1 hour and process them, just to access the JNDI should someone write Application Client , in my thought it has a whole different purpose somehow related with EJB, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can only inject EJB with container managed Beans i.e. Servlet, Session beans etc.

In your case you will have to locate Remote Interface through a JNDI lookup.

Example:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", remoteHost);
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", remotePort);

        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
        return ic.lookup(remoteInterface);
```

Comment: But my second EAR has an Application Client. This EAR is also deployed on the server. Shouldn't it work? I think you answer is for accesing EJB from an stand-alone java client (client that does not run in a container).

Comment: @B1eg - your example above using main(...) method to access the EJB which I believe you are calling through a command prompt. If that's the case then you must have to call EJB by a JNDI lookup. As I said above only container can inject the EJB at run time, any access outside the container has to be find by JNDI.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs usually when you have already deployed a project with the same JNDI name.

These are the steps to solve your problem:

1. First of all open your Glassfish/Payara server admin console.
2. Then go to the applications tab on the left sidebar.
3. Then undeploy the project that is present with the same JNDI Name.
4. Deploy the project again.

I hope this process will solve your problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Go through these sides

http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2007/06/simple-ejb-3-application-hand-made.html

http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2007/07/simple-ejb-3-servlet-application.html

[Classes of referenced EJB project not found in (the referencing) Web project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591056/classes-of-referenced-ejb-project-not-found-in-the-referencing-web-project)