# Want to create a session bean that will allow request from client desktop applicion

Tags: java, mysql, swing, ejb, persistence

im recently working on a java swing client application that uses ejb modules for functions or transactions. Im new to ejb technologies, i have already created a persistance file inside the ejb module folder that connects to a mysql database and also did a sample form containing a name and surname fields with a submit button to send the data to the database. Im looking on ways to test if theres connection between the client,ejb module and database.

Please advice

Comment: check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622385/access-ejb-from-application-client-project-configuration/5623166#5623166

Comment: @AndroidLearner: Formatting random words and names as code is not “improved formatting”. Please don’t do that in the future.